# .Click work with id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started using JQuery,  and i know you can use `.click` with a `class` but can you use .click using  `id` as the trigger ?  I have had a look around but i can't find any information on triggers.

Comment: I guess you didn't even try..

Comment: Who upvoted a question that shows the guy didn't even spent a moment to get an answer by himself???

Comment: The correct term in jQuery is `selector`, not `trigger`. This may be why you're not coming up with many resources when searching. Look at Jon's answer below.

Comment: @gdoron wasn't me, but I could easily ask the same question in reverse. Who downvoted a question that shows the guy may be new to jQuery and struggling to get started???

Comment: @KP. You should get started by reading the API! and the most important thing **TRY FIRST!!!**

Comment: @gdoron I agree completely the API should be a starting point. Clearly he was using the wrong terminology and needed some guidance to get started, and for all you know isn't even aware of what an API is. My point stands. A simple answer with a recommendation, link to API and example code is far more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id with click, but try using .live() (for jquery version < 1.7.1) and .on() (> jquery version 1.7.1) as it'll bind matching elements after the page is loaded.

so use.

```
$('#myid').on('click',function(e){
    //my code
});
```

or

```
$('#myid').live('click',function(e){
    //my code
});
```

depending on your jquery version

Comment: i wouldn't recommend live unless it is 100% necessary (which it rarely is) it's a performance nightmare!

Comment: @Patricia Additionally, `live` behaves slighty different than `click`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. As long as your element is identifiable in some way, any CSS selector will work, so an ID would just be:

```
$('#fooey').click(function() {
    // Handler code
});
```

Answer (score 3):

absolutely.  you can trigger click with pretty much any selector

```
$('#myId').trigger('click');
```

here is the jquery documentation on triggers:
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 3):

You must certainly can.

```
$("#unique_id").click(function() {
  // Disco
));
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

JQuery-function work on Dom-Elements regardless how they are selected:

- ids
- classes
- pseudoclasses
- pseudoelements
- attributes

You should take a look at [Selectors Docu of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Though I dislike the question, Excellent answer!

Comment: @gdoron I also dislike the question, but I prefer giving a qualified answer to beginners over bashing them. What I really hate are questions like "give me the code". Those are a definite -1 for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any valid selector to get your element and then trigger the click event

```
$('#element_id').click();
$('div #someelement > .oneChild').click();
```